# how to run software on client machine installed on server machine?

Tags: software-installation

I have two machine one with ubuntu 12.04 server and another with ubuntu 12.04 client.
i am having some software installed on ubuntu server machine. I need to use this software on client machine wihtout installing.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to access your server resources is by using `ssh` from your client.

First login into your server and `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`
You can easily identify your server ip address using `ifconfig`, just look for `inet addr:xxxxxxxx`

Then from you client type `ssh my_login@server_ip_address`

Comment: i have performed ssh operation on client machine but i need the command which we execute the software from /usr/share/application of server machine